# How to accept string as key for XOR Encryption program?

Tags: c++, encryption, xor

I'm trying to use a full user inputted string for the key in an encryption/decryption program. I'm also trying to figure out how to output the encryption as the original entered words but just with spaces, then encrypt (decrypt) again to get the word back to normal.

So for instance the user can enter their own sentence (hello world) and their own key (testkey), then the program encrypts it using testkey, outputs the result as "h e l l o w o r l d" for example. Then encrypts again and returns "hello world."

Any help would be appreciated, even if you can just help getting the user input for the key or the encryption output. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(){

 string sentence = "";
 string encrypted = "";
 string unencrypt = "";
 char key[] = "";

 cout << "Enter sentence: ";
 getline(cin, sentence);

 cout << "Enter key: ";
 cin >> key;

 for (int temp = 0; temp < sentence.size(); temp++){
  encrypted += sentence[temp] ^ (int(key) + temp) % 2;
 }
 cout << "Encrypted = " << encrypted;

 for (int temp = 0; temp < sentence.size(); temp++){
  unencrypt += sentence[temp] ^ (int(key) + temp) % 2;
 }
 cout << endl;
 cout << "Unencrypted = " << unencrypt;


 return 0;

}
```

Comment: i wouldn't call that encryption.

Comment: Yeah, I know but it's apparently required for part of a program...

Comment: I doubt you intended to XOR with an *address*.

Comment: `cin >> key;` attempts to read into a one-character array (the NUL terminator for `""`)... you can hardly fit your key in there.  Use another `std::string`, or an `int` if that's what you're ultimately trying to get.  BTW, the `std::string` constructor creates an empty string... no need for `= ""`.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Key deriving function. Generally, such keys are hashed with salt and the value of hash which is of fixed size can be used as keys. Salt is random.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function
It is a standard for deriving keys.

Comment: Would this still allow for user input of the key?

Comment: Yes. There is password that user can input.

Comment: Honestly I think it's above my current skill level at this point also it's not going to meet requirements. Thanks though! I'll check it out.

Comment: That is actually easy if you can use OpenSSL C APIs.

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out!